# accessing multiple values of array and returning them concatenated or as string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
const arr = ['a','c','o','l','s','t','r','i','n','g'];

let str = arr[1,2,2,3];

//returns l
```

What can i do to efficiently return `"cool"` which is what i want?

technically I'm doing this with all of the special characters as a way to reference them in string functions cause my code kept breaking otherwise.I found this fast, easy, and efficient;

The only reasonable solution I can think of is to capitalize the array and create a function with the lowered case and have that return a concatenated version. Am hoping for a better suggestion;

---update i  just did this:

```
function Spc(...theArgs) {
   let str = ""
   theArgs.forEach(function(element){ str += spc[element]; });
   return str;
}

 findbar.value = Spc(0,10,12)+".*"+Spc(10,12,1);
```

Comment: You can't give multiple indexes, you need a loop. You're using the comma operator, so it's equivalent to just `arr[3]`

Comment: What does capitalization have to do with it?

Comment: `let str = arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[2] + arr[3];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to access the array elements at each index and append them to the result string.

```js
const arr = ['a','c','o','l','s','t','r','i','n','g'];
let str = '';
[1, 2, 2, 3].forEach(index => str += arr[index]);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: I see you are using the index parameter of the forEach loop to target the correct index of the array, however in (element,index,array) the index would be the index of the array you're forEach looping over correct?  I just checked and yes the only reason this happens to work is because of the fact 'cool' is 1 indices in from the beginning of the array. consider
const arr = ['e','s','d','f','a','c','o','l','s','t','r','i','n','g'];
let str = '';
[1, 2, 2, 3].forEach(index => str += arr[index]);
document.write(str);   // sddf  <-- thanks but i gave the check to the proper answer

Comment: OK, i FINALLY got it now... you are mostly correct! i knew something was off tho. The index would be that of the array you are forEaching over. Therefor, you are actually using the element of the (element,index,array) arguments supplied to forEach.

Comment: Yes, it could be confusing. Usually the `index` parameter to the callback refers to the index in the array we're looping over. But in this case, the elements are indexes into another array, so I chose that name for the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the indices and map the characters. Then join the array to a string.

```js
const
    array = ['a', 'c', 'o', 'l', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'],
    indices = [1, 2, 2, 3],
    string = indices.map(i => array[i]).join('');

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of the indexes of the characters in 'arr', you can create a string as following:

```
const arr = ['a','c','o','l','s','t','r','i','n','g'];
const indexes = [1,2,2,3]

const concatenated = indexes.map(el => arr[el]); // result: ['c', 'o', 'o', 'l']
const string = concatenated.join(''); // result 'cool'
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I'd have chosen slightly different variable names: the `concatenated` variable doesn't contain something that was concatenated, but rather something that was mapped, so I'd named it `mapped`.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you prefer hard code here is what you can do to generate the string "cool". We simply create a new array of hard coded index values that generates the cool array and simply join them together!

```
 const arr = ['a','c','o','l','s','t','r','i','n','g'];
    
    let newArr = [arr[1],arr[2],arr[2],arr[3]];
```

> **newArr will be [c,o,o,l]**

```
    let string = newArr.join("");
```

> **string will be join with no spaces returning "cool"**

Comment: thats what i was hoping to avoid. repeatedly typing arr. thanks tho